# error running code with a realloc'ed array when reading int from file

Tags: c

So the initial capacity of the pointer is 5, then it will resizes itself depends on the numbers of integer in the file, after that i would like to print the read integer in the array out. But I got this error while running it.

```
ERROR:a.out: malloc.c:3574: mremap_chunk: Assertion `((size + offset) & (mp_.pagesize-1)) == 0' failed.
Aborted
```

(tons of stuffs afterward)

CODE:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>


    int main(void)
    {
    int index=0;
    int cap=5;
    int *arr = malloc(cap*sizeof(int));
    FILE *f;

    if((f=fopen("/home/alexchan/Downloads/fileOints000.txt","r"))==NULL)
    printf("You cannot open");

    int *y = arr;

    while(fscanf(f, "%d", arr++)!=EOF)
    {
    index++;
    if(index==cap)
    arr = realloc(arr, (cap +=10) * sizeof(int));
    }


    int x;
    for(x=0;x<index;x++)
    printf("%d\n",*(y++));

    return 0;


    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are setting `y` to point to your array, but forget to update its value when the array is reseated.

```
while(fscanf(f, "%d", arr++)!=EOF)
{
    index++;
    if(index==cap)  arr = realloc(arr, (cap +=10) * sizeof(int));
}

int *y = arr; // THIS SHOULD BE AFTER THE LOOP
```

`realloc` does not grow the array in place in the general case; it returns a totally different pointer. After this happens, the old value of `y` cannot be used anymore.

Comment: This doesnt work, i commented the printf part of the code, and the error still shown, that mean there is an error in while loop when i realloc the arr, any idea why??